# Speed in fetching data in mysql laravel 5

Tags: mysql, database, laravel-5

i have a products table and select data with two queries below and time are executed, it is shown in debugbar (two queries is only changed field to select, structure to query is the same each other):

```
select * from `products` order by `created_at` desc limit 11   670μs shop

select * from `images` where `images`.`product_id` in ('3', '2', '1') 650μs shop
```

and another.

```
select `id`, `name`, `price`, `code` from `products` order by `created_at` desc limit 11  1.19ms shop

select * from `images` where `images`.`product_id` in ('3', '2', '1') 800μs shop
```

i have reloaded more times and time to load "select * " is always lessthan "Select `id`, `name`, `price`, `code` ". 
So, does query with select all field is always faster than select specific columns and why?
Thanks!

Comment: Are these ( ` ) needed around column and table names?

Comment: @frederick99 That are probably queries generated by query builder.

Comment: oh. these (`) is debugbar of package in laravel generate it. the original query is 
                                 Products::with('image2')->select($field)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit($limit)->get();

Comment: yeah! @PaulSpiegel

Comment: What exactly is measured? Check the time for `Products::with('image2')->select('*')->...`

Comment: It is maybe because when a `*` is encountered, mysql knows what to return. But when it finds column names, it `select`s each column from the table, one-by-one probably, which takes more time. _Disclaimer: This is only a theory and I am not an expert in the field._

Comment: i think mean of @frederick99 is the same me @-PaulSpiegel.

Comment: I don't believe that `select *` can be faster. I also don't think that it would be significantly slower. For a simple query like this most time is probably spent with query building and network communication.

Comment: Thanks @PaulSpiegel. more query in a request maybe slower. but i still do not have an answer exactly! still waiting for expert :)